# Countdown, Timer & Alarm Clock software with very specific features

Tags: windows, calendar, time-management, productivity, notification

Looking for the following features, or help creating them myself, in an as small an amount of separate programs as possible.

**OS**: Windows 10.
Android would also be interesting, but strictly optional, or, (undesirably and as last resort): as an alternative.

---

## Desired features:

(Not in order of priority, that comes later)

#### Main:

1. **Alarm Clock**:

   - Multiple alarms
   - Repeat function (Daily, Weekly, Weekdays, Thursdays etc.)
2. **Countdown**:  You set either a

   ```
     a) period (say 4hrs), or  
     b) deadline (clock time AND/OR date) <-- Can be an extension of the "Alarm" feature.
   ```

   ...and it continually shows you how many days, hours, minutes, seconds are left till you reach 00:00:00

   - Multiple countdowns (I want multiple ones running at the same time)
3. **Timers/Stopwatch**: You click a button and it starts counting the amount of time elapsed.

   - Multiple Timers going at the same time

#### Other:

- SAVING \ LOGGING FUNCTIONS: I want to the app to log:

  - Timers especially (Alarm is a given):

    - Start time/date: When I started the timer
    - Time timed: The duration before I stopped the timer
    - Name: I want to be able to name my timer, especially if you'll have multiple ones running
  - If the Countdown is to take a deadline on a further date, obviously it needs to save said date so the countdown can survive a PC and/or Application reboot.
- ALWAYS VISIBLE TIMER STATUS:
  For example, the timer status is continuously reflected in the TASKBAR BUTTON, or (more annoying) a minimalistic "always on top" window with transparency.

---

## Priority:

It's a fantasy to get all of these features in one program, I think, so my biggest priorities, in order, are:

- Countdown and Timer, "Always visible"
- Multiple of each at the same time
- (Exigent, but I'd really like): Log at least the start time of each active timer

---

## **TL;DR**: There is none. Just skip what's below this line

---

*SIDE-NOTE: I have the utmost basic knowledge of **Python**, which I acquired in a few days, and just enough to create a script to help me import specific information from an online dictionary into an excel spreadsheet. So **if this is something I can easily create myself**, I'm okay with some pointers on how to go about teaching myself to do that (= a reference to modules I'll need, and I'll figure out how to make them work).*

---

I currently use a chrome app called **[Timer Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timer/edebbhkhcaafmolanelponjjanocpacd)**.

Pros:

- Does Countdown, Alarm, and Timer/Stopwatch
- Keeps running (counting) if Chrome browser or even the actual app's window is closed
- Countdown/Timer status visible in Taskbar

Cons:

- Can only run one of the three functions at a time
- Shockingly, it only allows you to specify an online YouTube video link as sound for the alarm
- None of the other features I mentioned

Comment: Did you try System Scheduler Professional? It doesn't have countdown feature but you can do this by snooze option. It has lots of settings. https://www.splinterware.com/ Please see virustotal results.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest taking a look at implementing this in Python with the [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) library for GUI elements.  wxPython is a python binding for the C++ GUI library they are both Free, Gratis, Open Source & Cross Platform.

*Note that if you are using Python 2.7 you need the downloads from [here](https://wxpython.org/download.php) but for Python 3.5 you will have to use the wxPython project [Phoenix](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip) installation.*

Be sure to install and try out the wxPython Docs & Demos especially the demos - they show you what you can do with the library. For python 2.7 this is available on the main download page but for python 3.x & phoenix you will need to fetch from [github](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix).

For date/time & time delta calculations check out the python builtin datetime.datetime and datetime.timedelta classes.

I would suggest storing the start/stop/duration information in either ini file format or json, builtin libraries exist for both but you could also consider using pickle to save the information.